# Led ceiling fan light turns off and on by itself

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan, led

I have had a remote controlled ceiling fan with the dimmable LED light for some time now and just recently the light turns off for about 1-2 second then back on. It stays on for about 5 seconds and then turns off again and so on. This only happens when the light is at its brightest setting.

Could this be a problem with the LEDs? Or with the electricity in my house?

Comment: *at its brightest setting* That means "dimmer". Is it a wall switch dimmer? Or is it a remote control fan/light dimmer?

Comment: I would blame the dimmer, try putting it about 1/4 inch from the end position

Comment: I would suspect that there is a thermal cutout that is getting to warm turning the fan off, when it cools just a bit it turns it back on. Post a link to technical information on the fan/light and is the dimmer separate or part of the fan assembly.